# Alternative to time trigger in google scripts

Tags: google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am creating a visual folder tree of my google drive in a spreadsheet (google sheets). However due to the size of the drive and using a BFS algorithm, I have to stop the script at a certain runtime and then restart from where it left off using a timed trigger.

Using the timed trigger creates issues with the data on the sheet (too specific to get into) but more importantly, it reaches the quota for when running and I get the service error.

My question is that can anyone think of a way or knows a way to bypass this issue and have the script run via some other way.

One thing I have considered:
-Activating remotely using a button on the sheet (but how to activate this button) since using manual triggering does not cause any problems.

Comment: Have you tried using time delays? Like [setTimeout()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)?

Comment: In what way are you suggesting using the setTimeout()?